# Observe single attribute of a object inside LiveData

Tags: kotlin, android-livedata

I've `Filter` class, with attributes like `maxPrice`; this is the relative `ViewModel`:

```kotlin
class FilterViewModel : ViewModel() {
    private val mutableLiveFilter = MutableLiveData<Filter>()
    val liveFilter: LiveData<Filter> get() = mutableLiveFilter

    fun setMaxPriceFilter(maxPrice: Int) { mutableLiveFilter.value?.maxPrice = maxPrice }
...
}
```

In a Fragment I have:

```kotlin
class FilterDialogFragment : BottomSheetDialogFragment() {
    private val filterViewModel: FilterViewModel by activityViewModels()
...
}
```

**Problem:**

When I invoke `setMaxPriceFilter(...)` from the Fragment, `filterViewModel` is updated also in the other fragments where I use it, but the callback

```kotlin
filterViewModel.liveFilter.observe(this) { collectFilter(it) }
```

isn't called. Instead, the callback `collectFilter(it)` is invoked when I change the whole `Filter` attached to the LiveData and not when I change only one attribute.

How can I observe the change of a single attribute of the `Filter` inside the LiveData?
Thanks.

Comment: Is Filter a mutable class? You could have it use LiveDatas for each of its properties and just make it a single instance (not wrapped in a LiveData) in the view model. Generally, it doesn’t make a lot of sense to use a mutable class in a LiveData. It’s hard to know what best to suggest without knowing more details.

Comment: Yes it is mutable, maxPrice and the other attributes are declared as var. So you suggest to have one LiveData for each Filter's attribute inside the FilterViewModel (instead of having a single Filter LiveData)?

Comment: I’m saying that’s one way it could be done, but I can’t recommend it without knowing more details. It might make more sense to change Filter to be an immutable class. Or to not even be a class and track things in separate LiveData of your ViewModel directly.

Comment: I followed your suggestion. I eliminated the Filter class and used only the FilterViewModel with a LiveData for each filter parameter. It is an elegant solution, thanks.